ヘルプ記事の翻訳：What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?
AI によって生成された文章を使った投稿に関するポリシーについて、ヘルプセンターに新しく記事が作られる予定です でアナウンスしたように https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy というヘルプページができており、この質問の投稿時点では英語なので、翻訳したいです。
Community wiki 形式で原文を回答として投稿いたしますので、有志で翻訳いたしましょう。翻訳が固まり次第、モデレーターがヘルプページを翻訳後のものに更新します。
また、原文で参照されている https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage も翻訳を必要としています。これは ポリシーの翻訳：Inauthentic usage policy で議論されているのでそちらで進めます。

生成AIによって作られたコンテンツに対するこのサイトのポリシー
生成AI（GPT、LLM、生成的人工知能、generative AI、genAI）のツールによってコンテンツを作り $SiteName で使うことは可能ですが、我々のガイドに則り、生成AIの利用を示すように適切な参照を含む必要があります。もし投稿されたコンテンツが生成AIによって書かれたものと判定され、かつ適切な参照を含んでいなかった場合、そのコンテンツは削除される可能性があります。またその場合、それによって生まれた信用度も元に戻ります。AIによって生成されたコンテンツを参照なしに投稿した場合、モデレーターにより警告される場合もあります。繰り返し違反した場合はアカウントの停止に繋がります。
Stack Exchangeネットワーク上にある他のいくつかのサイトでは、生成AIに対して異なるポリシーを運用していることがあります。場合によっては生成AI製のコンテンツの投稿を完全に禁止していることもあるほどです。それぞれのサイトに投稿する前に、そのサイトでのポリシーをよく確認してください。
生成AIによって生成されたコンテンツとみなされる基準は何ですか？
生成AIによって生成されたコンテンツとは、与えたプロンプトを元に自動的に応答を書き出すようなツールを使い、一部もしくは全体が作られたコンテンツのことを指します。ここでいうツールには、ChatGPTやGoogle Geminiのような大規模言語モデルを含みます。このようなツールは本物の受け答えを真似した文章を答えるように訓練されているため、出力された返答は一見もっともらしく見えるかもしれません。しかし生成された回答の品質はものによって大きく異なり、場合によっては全く異なった回答になっていることもあります。
このため、もし大規模言語モデル（LLM）を利用して $SiteName のためのコンテンツを書いている場合、そうしていることが適切に参照されるようにしてください。
コンテンツの作成に、生成AIサービスを利用して書いたことを開示する必要があるのはなぜですか？
Stack Exchangeは、コミュニティメンバーによって開発・維持される共同リソースであり、高品質で精査された知識の蓄積を目指しています。前述のように、生成AIツールによるコンテンツは見た目や内容がもっともらしく感じられることがありますが、その質には大きく異なる可能性があります。そのため、投稿されたコンテンツがこれらのツールやサービスを利用して生成されたものであることを、将来の読者に明確に伝えることが非常に重要です。これにより、読者はコンテンツの限界や欠点を十分に理解し、その有用性を適切に判断できるようになります。
大規模言語モデルによって生成されたコンテンツには、適切な参照がないままでは $SiteName での使用に適さない、重要な問題点がいくつかあります :

ユーザーが $SiteName で質問をしたとき、そのあと投稿される回答は人間によって書かれ人間によって精査されたものだろうと期待します。そうすることで、他の人の基準に照らし合わせても、その回答が事実に基づいており、質問と関連した内容で、完結しているものであることを保証します。人間が書くことは完璧ではありませんが、生成AIは質問のニュアンスを表現する重要な要素を考慮しないことがありますし、質問に関係するかしないかに関わらずすべてを詳しく説明しだすといったように回答に過剰なノイズを加えたりもします。場合によっては誤った情報や誤解を招く情報を作ってしまうこともあります。
$SiteName で質問をするユーザーは、既に他の場所で回答を探しているかもしれません。生成AIサービスを使った人もいるでしょう。適切な参照を書くことで、回答を読んだときにその投稿を読みたいかどうか決めやすくなりますし、生成AIを使って書かれた投稿にありがちな危うさに注意することもできます。
時に、生成AIはコンテンツの生成ではなく編集や翻訳の補助に使用されることがあります。この場合でも、生成というよりもむしろ変換的なアクションとはいえ、これらのツールは依然としてエラーを起こす可能性があり、元のテキストに存在しない新しい情報を含めてしまうことがあります。
生成AIは、Stack Exchange ネットワークの基準に合った形でナレッジの出典を参照することができません。生成AIが回答に対して出典を示しているように見えても、その出典は元の質問に関連しているとは限らず、全く存在しない可能性さえもあります。$SiteName においては、コンテンツがナレッジの出典を正直かつ公正に表現できていない場合があり、誰かが生成AIを作成者として明記しても、実際のオリジナルの著者が適切にクレジットされていない場合もあります。

たとえ適切に出典を参照している場合でも、これらのツールによって生成されたコンテンツを短期間に頻繁に投稿すると、$SiteName に不要な混乱が生じる可能性があり、行動規範の不正使用ポリシーに違反することになりますのでご注意ください。
生成AIツールによって生成されたコンテンツの参照方法は？
より一般的な他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法 は、生成AIツールによって生成されたコンテンツに適用されます。具体的には、次の2つの点に注意する必要があります:

生成AIツールが生成されたコンテンツと、それ以外を明確に区別すること。 そうする事によってツールの出力から直接引用している部分とあなた自身が作成した部分、または他の出典から引用している部分の違いなどが明らかになります。
利用した具体的な生成AIツールやサービスを明記すること。 サービスによって同じプロンプトに対して異なる出力が生成されることがあり、それぞれの制限や欠点も異なるため、どのツールを使って生成されたコンテンツなのかを読者が把握できるようにすることが重要です。

プロンプトの詳細を共有する際、プロンプトや出力を完全にコピーペーストする必要はありません。自分が作者ではないコンテンツを参照する場合と同様に、全文をコピーするのではなく、そのコンテンツの言葉やアイデアを自分の内容を補強するために使用する方が良いでしょう。以下は、生成AIツールが生成した素材を投稿の中で引用する例です :

[生成AIサービス]に[部分的なプロンプト]について尋ねました。その出力は次のとおりです :

[生成AI の応答]

[投稿を完成させるために必要なその他のソース、引用、説明等]

このポリシーが実際にはどのように適用されるかについての質問がある場合は、メタ $SiteNameで、これらのコンテンツに関する過去のまたは進行中の議論がありコミュニティの規範が確立されているかどうかを確認してください。もしそのような議論がなく懸念事項に対処していない場合、他のコミュニティメンバーが意見を提供できるように自分でディスカッションを開始することを検討してください。
Are there alternatives to using generative artificial intelligence services to craft answers?
Many of the answers on $SiteName are created by users sharing their own expertise. In particular, when supplying answers outside their expertise, users should reference trustworthy sources. Searching for sources, synthesizing them into a good answer, and referencing them clearly are critical steps in developing a well-crafted answer.
Remember - the person who asked a question needs a correct answer. As such, answering correctly is always more important than answering quickly. Additionally, our system thrives on questions getting multiple good answers, which are more likely to help future visitors who have the same question. By following a process that creates consistently correct answers of good quality, and that are well-referenced as needed, you should do just fine here.
